# DISTINCT count on a ref_cursor in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, distinct

I have some code where I create a ref cursor within Oracle PL/SQL to be able to loop through the resulting rows. The table has one large pipe delimited text string column which I then loop through to get the x position array value

(eg: if the lines are all like 'Mike|Male|100|Yes|UK' and 'Dave|Male|200|No|UK' then I have a formula that allows the array position to be passed to the function to return an array of the resulting values

array position 1 call returns 'Mike' and 'Dave'
array position 2 call returns 'Male' and 'Male'

What is the best way to approach it if I want to be able to have a function that returns the distinct values of an array position

so array position 1 call would return 2
array position 2 call would return 1

I'm quite new to PL/SQL so please excuse the dumb question!

Splitting the source table into individual columns is not an option unfortunately :-(

Many thanks

Mike

IN response to @zero323 (apologies for missing this out)

Sample code so far is...

```
FUNCTION DistinctInterfacelineValues(
    inArrayPos     NUMBER,
    inSessionIdMIN NUMBER,
    inSessionIdMAX NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  int_cursor interfaceline_refcursor_type;
  runningTotal NUMBER:=0;
  tempValue    NUMBER:=0;
  int_record inttestintrecs%ROWTYPE;
  lineLength INTEGER:=1;
  distinctCount NUMBER:=0;

  TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
  tempTable  table_type;
  tempTablePos INTEGER:=1;

BEGIN

 OPEN int_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM inttestintrecs WHERE (sessionid>=inSessionIdMIN AND sessionid <=inSessionIdMAX);
  LOOP
    FETCH int_cursor INTO int_record;
    EXIT
  WHEN int_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    lineLength := LENGTH(int_record.interfaceline) - LENGTH(REPLACE(int_record.interfaceline, '|', '')) + 1;
    FOR i                                         IN 1 .. lineLength
    LOOP
      IF i            =inArrayPos THEN
***VALUE HERE IS 'Mike' or 'Dave' DEPENDING ON LOOP POSITION***
***I WANT TO KNOW COUNT THE DISTINCT VALUES HERE***
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE int_cursor;
  RETURN runningTotal;



END DistinctInterfacelineValues;
```

Comment: @zero323 - main post amended. Sorry about that. Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need PL/SQL for this; you can use `regexp_substr`:

```
select count(distinct value)
from (
  select regexp_substr(interfaceline, '[^|]+', 1, :arrayPos) as value
  from inttestintrecs
  where sessionid between :loSessId and :hiSessId
);
```

... where the bind variables are the values you were passing to the function. If you really want a function for that you can just wrap the query (updated with tbone's `replace` trick to deal with null values):

```
create or replace function DistinctInterfacelineValues(
    inArrayPos     NUMBER,
    inSessionIdMIN NUMBER,
    inSessionIdMAX NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  distinctCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select count(distinct value)
  into distinctCount
  from (
    select trim(regexp_substr(replace(interfaceline, '|', ' |'),
      '[^|]+', 1, inArrayPos)) as value
    from inttestintrecs
    where sessionid between inSessionIdMIN and inSessionIdMAX
  );
  RETURN distinctCount;
END;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85409/1).

---

Within the nested loop version you posted, you *could* maintain a PL/SQL table indexed by the value rather than a number:

```
...
  TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100); 
  tempTable  table_type;
  tempValue VARCHAR2(100);
...
      IF i = inArrayPos THEN
        tempValue := regexp_substr(int_record.interfaceline, '[^|]+', 1, i);
        tempTable(tempValue) := 1;
      END IF;
...
  RETURN tempTable.count;
...
```

[Another Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76073/1) just for fun, but there's really no point having all the PL/SQL loop overhead, particularly with the `regexp_substr` in the middle anyway. You could increment the count held in `tempTable` for each value so you knew how many of each you'd seen, and you could get the actual values from `tempTable` too... but you can get those from the pure SQL version just as easily (selecting `value, count(*)` and `distinct value`).

Comment: One other very quick question if I may

Comment: @Mike- I looked at your follow-up question and couldn't see a quick fix; but tbone's answer to that works - [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65d33/3). I updated the answer to include that too.